# Trying to understand backbone inheritance and specialization

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a base view `V`:

```
V = Backbone.View.extend({   
  initialize: function() {
    console.log(this.options.z);
    console.log(this.options.q);   
  }
});
```

extended by `VV`, which sets the value of a property (`q: 234`):

```
VV = V.extend({q:234});
```

`V` is further specialized to `VV`:

```
new VV({z: 123})
```

​
The problem is that the base type has no access to `q`, how can I do this?
I'm trying to understand this inheritance system, in this example
`q` and `z` are like virtual/abstract values that are to be defined in
sub classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/maxl/G8cab/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say this:

```
VV = V.extend({q: 234});
```

you're creating `VV` as "subclass" of `V` that will have an extra `q` property. The properties defined by the "class" have nothing to do with the automatic options handling from [`View#initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

The documentation might be better if it said "creating a new *instance* of the View".

Then, when you `new VV({z: 123})`, that `{z: 123}` is passed to the view's `initialize` method in its single `options` parameter (pre-1.1.0 Backbones automatically set `this.options` to the constructor's options) the `q` will be in `this.q` so your `initialize` should look more like this:

```
initialize: function(options) {
  console.log(options.z);
  console.log(this.q);
}
```

Also, if you did this:

```
var VVV = VV.extend({q: 'pancakes'});
```

you'd be replacing the default `q` that instances of `VV` get and `this.q` would be `'pancakes'` inside `initialize`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eqBV2/

Using [`View#extend`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend) is like subclassing (or more accurately it creates a new prototypical instance) whereas `new` creates new objects (or copies of the prototypical instance). Of course, the class/instance language doesn't fit the reality of JavaScript so we have to be careful not to take the terminology too seriously.